# Two way login in my Spring web MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, basic-authentication

Application built on Spring web MVC. Spring Security version is 3.1.0. Application already have a login form based authentication system.

Now I want to introduce another authentication system (along with the existing one) for the whole application. Requirements for the new auth system as below:

1. user will hit a specific controller end point
2. browser will generate a request to server and request header will contain a encrypted token as credentials.
3. Server will read the token and decrypt the token.
4. Server will verify user information taken from decrypted token.
5. Server will redirect after successful authentication to main application url (e.g. example.com)

To achieve these requirements: I have implemented as below:

Spring-security.xml

```
<bean id="authEntryPoint" class="com.example.authProvider.AuthEntryPoint"/>
<bean id="authFilter" class="com.example.authProvider.AuthFilter"/>
<bean id="authProvider" class="com.example.authProvider.AuthProvider" />

<http pattern="/**/basic-login.html" create-session="stateless" use-  expressions="true" auto-config="true"
          authentication-manager-ref="authManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint"/>
    <custom-filter ref="authFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager id="authManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="authProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

AuthEntryPoint.java

```
public class AuthEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authEx.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    setRealmName("example.com");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}
}
```

AuthFilter.java

```
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String xAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String info = request.getHeader("encryptedInfo");
    //decrypt the info and verify the info. if info not valid throw 401 status. 

    if (info != valid) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Token-invalid");
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

AuthProvider.java

```
public class AuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    User user= loadUserFromDB(username);

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}

private User loadUserFromDB(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    //implement to load user from db
    return new User(username, password, true,
            true, true, true,
            Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
}
}
```

How can I implement the `onAuthenticationSuccess` handler? as it is basic-authentication process?

To clarify, look in `<form-logn>` tag there is a attribute named authentication-success-handler-ref where I can add onAuthenticationSuccess handler. but in `<http-basic>` tag, there is no such attribute, right? So how can I set onAuthenticationSuccess handler?

Comment: I have added your text to the question. I will cast a reopen vote for it now as I don't have Spring skills; in my estimation the question is clearer. Could I ask you though to edit the question if the spelling of `<form-logn>` is incorrect - should that be `<form-login>`?

Comment: @halfer - sure. thanks